# Grep matching cell of the csv file and index of that row

Tags: text-processing, scripting, grep, cut, csv-simple

I have csv file and I want to see numbers that start with `0.99` and their row's index which is the first cell of that row.

This is what I have so far:

```
cat fil.csv | grep '0\\.99'| tee > (cut -d, -f1) | tr , \\n |  grep '0\\.99'
```

input:

```
id, f1,f2,f3
f1,0.54,0.12,0.432
f2,0.1231,0.99999,0.99832
f3,0.121,nan,0.12321
f4,0.99712,0.121,0.434
```

desired output:
ideally i want this but it would be too complex for oneliner:

```
f2,0.99999,0.99832
f4,0.99712
```

I can settle for this, which is what I want from the command that I wrote:

```
f2
0.99999
0.99832
f4
0.99712
```

Comment: You can use just one GNU `grep` : `grep -own '0\.99\w*'`

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
$ awk -F, '$0~"0\\.99*"{printf $1;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~"0\\.99*"){printf ","$i}};printf "\n"}'
f2,0.99999,0.99832
f4,0.99712
```

In more readable form:

```
$ awk -F, '
      $0~"0\\.99*"{
          printf $1
          for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
              if($i~"0\\.99*"){
                  printf ","$i
              }
          }
          printf "\n"
      }
  '
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `perl`:

```
$ perl -F, -anle '
  BEGIN { $, = "," }
  @h = grep { /^0\.99/ } @F;
  print $F[0], @h if @h;
' file
f2,0.99999,0.99832
f4,0.99712
```